# Cq ui clientlib is not accessible

Tags: widget, aem

I have util page that used in publish enviromets. HtmlLibraryManager is used to include  ui

```
<%
        HtmlLibraryManager htmlMgr = sling.getService(HtmlLibraryManager.class);
        if (htmlMgr != null) {
            htmlMgr.writeCssInclude(slingRequest, out, "cq.wcm.edit");
            htmlMgr.writeJsInclude(slingRequest, out, "cq.wcm.edit");
        }        
%>
```

But some requested libs doesn't loaded

`/libs/cq/ui/widgets.js` and `/libs/cq/ui/rte.js`

They brokes my page.

Also if I will try to acces them `http://servername:port/libs/cq/ui/widgets.js` , error is returned:

> The requested file cannot be found.

How could I get access to this clientlibs?

AEM 6.0 is used.

I have found follwing error in log file:

```
23.09.2015 11:03:55.124 *ERROR* [172.18.251.90 [1443020634874] GET /libs/cq/ui/widgets.js HTTP/1.1] com.day.cq.widget.impl.HtmlLibraryManagerImpl Error while saving changes: javax.jcr.RepositoryException: Error during assembly of /libs/c
q/ui/widgets.js. reverting.
23.09.2015 11:03:55.124 *ERROR* [172.18.251.90 [1443020634874] GET /libs/cq/ui/widgets.js HTTP/1.1] com.day.cq.widget.impl.HtmlLibraryManagerImpl Error while sending cached library: javax.jcr.RepositoryException: Error during assembly of
 /libs/cq/ui/widgets.js
23.09.2015 11:03:55.125 *ERROR* [172.18.251.90 [1443020634874] GET /libs/cq/ui/widgets.js HTTP/1.1] com.day.cq.widget.impl.HtmlLibraryServlet Cannot create library for /libs/cq/ui/widgets.js
java.io.IOException: Error while sending cached library: javax.jcr.RepositoryException: Error during assembly of /libs/cq/ui/widgets.js
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in courrupted lib. See more at [adobe forum](http://help-forums.adobe.com/content/adobeforums/en/experience-manager-forum/adobe-experience-manager.topic.html/forum__zba0-i_have_utilpagetha.html)